For a modern Turboprop/Jet will going at 300/400 mph TAS at 10000 feet require more thurst/use more fuel per unit time vs going 600mph at 30,000 feet?
My understanding is one of the primary reasons why modern planes Cruise at around 30,000 to 40,000 ft is because of the lower air density less results in less drag. So for a given thrust, an airplane can fly faster at a higher altitude ...
However, how does fuel efficiency figure in ? To generate the given thrust does the plane require less fuel? Use a simplified toy example (Scenario A) to At 300 mph True Air speed. At 10,000 ft. Versus flying at 600 mph at 30,000 ft. Will flying 600 mph at 30,000 ft require both less thrust and use less fuel per unit time versus 300 mph at 10,000 ft, ?
Or (Scenario B): Are talking about requiring less thrust and less fuel per unit time for equivalent Air Speeds at different altitudes? That is, is flying at 300 mph at 30,000 ft requires less thrust and consumes less fuel per unit time than 300 mph at 10000 ft (assuming 300 mph is sufficient speed to generate lift at that altitude of 30000 ft of lower air density). Let us ignore like jet engine efficiency for now at given altitude, And just focus on drag drag, thrust and fuel consumption...I know modern engines are also optimized to work at certain altitude window etc
Actually it occurred to me I may have got it all kind of backwards. The Same amount of thrust at a higher altitude translates to greater True air speed- due to lower drag due to lower air density at higher altitudes. This means you cover more distance for same amount of fuel! It is fuel per unit distance (miles per gallon) that is reduced, not fuel consumption per se (Liters per unit of Thrust)  it Scenario A while going 600 mph at 30000 feet at constant thrust may use similar fuel per unit TIME vs 300 mph at 10000 feet, it will likely use less fuel per unit DISTANCE traveling greater distance per GALLON not necessarily per unit TIME  or Thrust. As for Scenario B: Obviously going 300 mph at 30000 feet (assuming 300 mph is sufficient to generate enough lift at 30000 feet with lower air density) will use less fuel per unit time and thrust than going 300 mph at 10000 ft (due to lower drag due to lower air density at higher altitudes) Is this understanding correct track?

Actually it occurred to me I may have got it all kind of backwards. The Same amount of  thrust at a higher altitude translates to greater True air speed- due to lower drag due to lower air density at higher altitudes. This  means  you cover more distance for same amount of fuel! It is fuel per unit distance (miles per gallon) that is reduced, not fuel consumption per se (Liters per unit of Thrust )

please delete this useless comment ... the same is in the question

You need to constrain the problem better. For instance, make the comparison at a fixed coefficient of lift. Each plane has a best cruise CoL. The latest generation will be in the 0.5 to 0.6 range when carrying a decent load, maybe 0.4 when light. Also, the normal measure of merit is consumption per unit distance,  not consumption per unit time, unless you are killing time in a landing pattern.

The answer is published for every commercial airplane covering many different flight conditions. Large tables of range, thrust, and fuel consumption rates are published for different weights, altitudes, engine conditions, deicing on/off, cabin air conditioning, one-engine-loss, etc.
There are also published optimal flight altitude profiles for transiting various distances with minimal fuel consumption and various airport altitudes. These are quite a hassle to generate and can produce some pretty weird looking flight profiles.
See here for some charts on the A320. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/106506/does-an-airplane-fly-less-or-more-efficiently-after-an-mid-flight-engine-failure
